# Почему не работает добавление стилей?

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает добавление стилей через функцию `aplyStyles()`? 
Пробовал отлаживать код, вроде все верно, `key = 'display', styles[key] = 'none'`

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.cube_vertical');

function aplyStyles(elem, styles) {
  
  for(var key in styles) {
    elem.style.key = styles[key];  
  }

}


aplyStyles(slides[0], {display: 'none'});
```

```css
* {
  marign: 0 auto;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.cube_vertical {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  
}

.cube_vertical:first-child {
  background-color: #74b9ff;
}

.cube_vertical:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #6c5ce7;
}

.cube_vertical:last-child {
  background-color: #ff7675;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что не style.key, а style[key]

Answer (score 1):

Вы устанавливаете значения свойства `key` а не желаемого свойства

```
elem.style.key = styles[key];
```

Вот так надо

```
elem.style[key] = styles[key];
```

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.cube_vertical');

function aplyStyles(elem, styles) {
  
  for(var key in styles) {
    elem.style[key] = styles[key];  
  }

}


aplyStyles(slides[0], {display: 'none'});
```

```css
* {
  marign: 0 auto;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.cube_vertical {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  
}

.cube_vertical:first-child {
  background-color: #74b9ff;
}

.cube_vertical:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #6c5ce7;
}

.cube_vertical:last-child {
  background-color: #ff7675;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
  <div class="cube_vertical">

  </div>
</div>
```